# Reporting Services Rendering format restriction

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, format, restriction

Is there any way I can restrict my rendering format to PDF for one of my report in Report Manager?

Thanks,
brijit

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the report server call and use [URL access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586(SQL.90).aspx) (or SOAP etc) to deliver a PDF.

```
http://servername/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary&rs:Format=PDF&rs:Command=Render
```

It's can't be done via Report manager

Comment: But this case wont work when I have input parameters for the report . right?

Comment: Yes. You can pass them on the URL too.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391(SQL.90).aspx

The downside is that you have to expose the parameters via another method (ASP.NET, Winforms etc).

Comment: I understand that.But, my users are  accessing the report from Report Manager itself. They can even subscribe the report execution. Then they will be having all the rendering formats that is common to the reporting services. right?

Comment: Here we go (courtesy of a colleague) http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/roman/archive/2004/12/12/5506.aspx 
Downside: I think (not tried myself) it applies to the install, not an individual report.